# Using array values to select database table in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have this sorted array with top 5 products

```
foreach ($bestsellers as $item) {
      $data = json_decode($item->order_details, true);
      $product_ids[] = key($data);
}
      arsort($product_ids);
      $three = array_unique(array_slice($product_ids, 0, 5, true));
      print_r($three);
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 2 
    [2] => 3 
    [3] => 4 
    [4] => 5
)
```

`1,2,3,4,5` are products id's. Is it possible to use this values in the query to products table so I can display on page more information about the products. Not just the ID.

Something like

```
Product::where('product_id', $value);
```

Update

```
$best = Product::whereIn('product_id', $three)->get();

foreach($best as $info)
{
    dd($info->title);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You should use `whereIn` for array. In fact, `whereIn` takes second parameter as array of values for specified column.

```
Product::whereIn('product_id', $value);
```

[whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

> The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained
>   within the given array:

Comment: Do I need addition loop to get values or I can use it like `Product::whereIn('product_id', $product_ids);`?

Comment: dont need to use loop , ```whereIn``` check all values in array

Comment: I've updated my question. This is returning only one result. Why is that?

Comment: @Ivan You need `->get()` at the end to get product detail whose id is in given array

Comment: @SagarGautam Yes, there is `->get();` at the end of the query

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I've used `dd` to see results and `dd` stops after first result.

Comment: @Ivan you shouldnt use dd in foreach loop it return first one